# NUnitLite in Xamarin (Android). Unable to load Mono.Data.Sqllite.dll

Tags: android, nunit, xamarin

I'm currently experimenting with Xamarin for the first time, as well as NUnitLite for the first time. I've set up a small Android project and a test project. In the Android project I make use of SqlLite, and in my test project I want to write some integration tests for my database insert/update/select methods.

However, when I run tests which includes a call to my class "GroupRepository" (which includes a type from the Mono.Data.Sqllite.dll in its constructor) I get the following exception. Note that I've also added the mentioned dll to my test-project.

```
TestInsertWithLegalValues (IntegrationTests.Repository.RepositoryTests.TestInsertWithLegalValues)
   System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Data.Sqlite, version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
  ----> System.Security.SecurityException : Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
   at Repository.GroupRepository..ctor()
   at IntegrationTests.Repository.RepositoryTests.SetUp()
--SecurityException
```

The Android project targets API 8 using Xamarin 2.0. The test project is a Windows Console Application .NET 4.5.

Why is this failing the way it is?

Thanks for any input!